# Azure Functions Timer Trigger thread safety

Tags: azure, cron, azure-functions

I was wondering if anybody knows what happens if you have a Cron setting on an Azure Function to run every 5 minutes if its task takes more than 5 minutes to execute. Does it back up? Or should I implement a locking feature that would prevent something, say in a loop, from handling data already being processed by a prior call?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Azure function with timer trigger will only run one job at a time. If a job takes longer then next one is delayed.

Quoting from [Wiki](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/wiki/TimerTrigger#scheduling)

> If your function execution takes longer than the timer interval,
>   another execution won't be triggered until after the current
>   invocation completes. The next execution is scheduled after the
>   current execution completes.

That is true even if you scale out.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer#scale-out

You may want to ensure that your function does not time out on you. See https://buildazure.com/2017/08/17/azure-functions-extend-execution-timeout-past-5-minutes/ on how to configure function timeout.

Comment: I'll add - If you want executions of your timer function to be able to overlap, instead have the timer write a message to a queue and put your logic in a queue triggered function.

Comment: This information is incorrect! The linked documentation is for WebJobs which will execute as described. An Azure Function App will run in parallel if it does not complete by the next scheduled time.

Comment: I beg to differ. According to following link funtions use TimerTrigger from webjobs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp

Comment: I does run another instance in parallel.

Comment: I can confirm it does NOT run additional invocations if you are running using a `TimerTrigger`. I have a 1 minute timer trigger and my job takes between 3 and 7 minutes to complete, but the Function only ever has one execution running at any given time. This accepted answer is correct as written

Answer (score 1):

If a timer trigger occurs again before the previous run has completed, it will start a second parallel execution.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference#parallel-execution

> When multiple triggering events occur faster than a single-threaded function runtime can process them, the runtime may invoke the function multiple times in parallel.

Something else to note is that even using the new `WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT` settings, you cannot prevent multiple executions on the same instance.

> Each instance of the function app, whether the app runs on the Consumption hosting plan or a regular App Service hosting plan, might process concurrent function invocations in parallel using multiple threads.

The best advice is to either reduce the duration it takes to execute, through optimisation or changing the approach to the problem. Perhaps splitting the task down and triggering it in a different way may help.

Comment: I read this as that in general function would to try to run in parallel unless there is something specific in the trigger (like timer trigger) that would override this behavior.